# Clear modal views from memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, segue

I'm currently having the problem that my storyboard has beside the navigation controller some modal views to separate them from the main "route" in my app.
So when I press a button a modal segue opens the other view.

The problem is: when I go back to the navigation controller and I press the button to open the modal view again, it creates a new instance of the view controller without deleting the old one.

Is it possible to clean up the memory when leaving from the modal view or something?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't delete the old one from the memory?

Comment: Yes, I am, I added a NSLog to the dealloc of the views to notify me, when it is deleted, but I already found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

When you are finished with your separated modal view part, you just use
`[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and the app goes back to the last view controller, in this case the UINavigationController.
And with this, it also deallocates the old views.